# Sort the balance column in ruby on rails 6

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I am trying to calculate and sort the balance column in the table as per the image shown below;

[image]

For that, I used  `@mexpenses = @mexpenses.sort { |e| e.balance }` for sorting as it results in undesired results so I commented out in the code below.

I would like to achieve the results as shown in the rightmost **BALANCE** column in the above image.

Everything in the table from the **Date** column to the **Debit** column is shown as desired only the **Balance** column is causing the issue.

I would like to get the latest record at the top of the statement with the appropriate balance.

Note: No balance column is in the database.

mexpenses_controller.rb

```
def index
  @mexpenses = Mexpense.order('date DESC')
  balance = 763.87
  @mexpenses.each do |e|
    balance += e.credit.to_f - e.debit.to_f
    e.balance = balance
  end

  # @mexpenses = @mexpenses.sort { |e| e.balance }  

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xls 
  end
end
```

Mexpense.rb

```
class Mexpense < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :particulars, presence: true
    validates :date, presence: true
    
    attr_accessor :balance

    after_initialize :init

    def init
        self.balance = 0
    end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

      <div class="table-responsive myTable">

        <table class="table listing text-center">
          <tr class="tr-head">
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Particulars</td>
            <td>Credit</td>
            <td>Debit</td>
            <td>Balance</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>


          <% @mexpenses.each do |mexpense| %>

          <tr class="tr-<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">

            <td class="col-1"><%= mexpense.date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') %></td>

            <td class="col-1" style="width: 50%;"><%= link_to mexpense, mexpense %></td>

            <td class="col-1 neg" style="width: 10%;"><%= number_with_precision(mexpense.credit, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

            <td class="col-1 pos" style="width: 10%;"><%= number_with_precision(mexpense.debit, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>


            <td><%= number_with_precision(mexpense.balance, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

          </tr>

          <% end %>

        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

20210213052730_create_mexpenses.rb

```
class CreateMexpenses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :mexpenses do |t|
      t.date :date
      t.string :particulars
      t.decimal :debit
      t.decimal :credit

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use [`sort_by`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by) instead of [`sort`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/sort)?

Comment: Also, I don't think your "desired result" is correct. That looks like you've sorted the values **as a string**, not a number, and therefore are getting weird ordering when there's a thousands separator in the value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used sort_by but still not working. How do I sort as a number.

Answer (score 0):

1. I strongly recommend to store the `balance` column in the database. Each time `debit` or `credit` is changed, the `balance` column will be updated.
2. store MONEY as `integer`!!!! This avoids floating point rounding errors.

console:

```
rails g migration add_balance_to_mexpenses balance:integer
```

migration:

```
add_column :mexpenses, :balance, :integer, default: 0, null: false
```

mexpence.rb - update balance column whenever a `mexpence is changed

```
after_save do
  update :balance, credit - debit
end
```

Now you can easily order by balance that is a separate field in your database. Something like:

```
@mexpenses = Mexpense.order(date: :desc, balance: :desc)
```

Comment: I second the suggestion to store the balance in the database. But using `decimal` as a column type is okay because that would use `BigDecimal` internally when done right and would not suffer from float precision issues.

Comment: Storing balance in database requires callbacks to update all depending records in case of updating/deleting a row. Also: debit and credit are already decimal; initial balance is `balance = 763.87`; balance is calculated as `balance += e.credit.to_f - e.debit.to_f` then sorted, so, it is already sorted as number. The problem is maybe elsewhere.

Comment: Where might be the problem, I want to know and resolve as I tried hours and days but unable to sort out.